# MYSQL Stored Procedure not updating column

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters

I have been working this all day, trying to get a simple Stored procedure in MYSQL to work like I want it to.
This is the Stored Procedure I am using:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE DEFINER=`vhabot`@`%` PROCEDURE `Update_Players`(in uid VARCHAR(64), in cname varchar(45),in rank_name varchar(20), in clevel int, in defrank int, in cfaction varchar(15), in org varchar(100), in today date)
BEGIN
DECLARE Records INT;
DECLARE Updt bool DEFAULT 'TRUE';
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO Records FROM dim5players where TRIM(id) = TRIM(uid);
If Records = 0 THEN
INSERT INTO dim5players (id, `name`, rank_name, `level`, defender_rank_id, Organization, `Date`, Updated)
VALUES (uid,cname, rank_name, clevel, defrank, cfaction, org, today, Updt ); 
END IF;

UPDATE dim5players SET Updated=true WHERE `name` = TRIM(cname);

END$$
```

All I want it to do is check if an id (primary key) already exists by using Counting the records that may have the ID. If the count is 0 then I can add the record with the input parameters above.

Regardless of if a record is inserted or not, I want all records that have has the 'name' that matches the input of name to be given 'true' in the updated column.

Regardless of what I do, it never updates the 'true' value in the updated column. Somewhere in this SP something is not right. I am just not sure where it is.

Answer (score 1):

Your stored procedure is not required for this use case. Instead do this:

```
INSERT INTO dim5players
(id, name, rank_name, level, defender_rank_id, Organization, `Date`, Updated)
VALUES 
(TRIM(uid), TRIM(cname), rank_name, clevel, defrank, cfaction, org, today, TRUE)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
Updated = VALUES(Updated);

UPDATE dim5players SET Updated = TRUE WHERE name = TRIM(cname);
```

This will perform much better for several reasons:

1. Stored procedures are always slower than doing straight SQL.
2. The clause `where TRIM(id) = TRIM(uid)` will not use an index, but will always scan the entire table.
3. Race conditions are avoided.